# Applying a mask on another mask (or AND condition) for image analysis

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to do an AND operation on two masks to get their co-positive pixels but it doesn't seem to work - I get the original mask somehow after the AND operation:

```
plt.imshow(mask);plt.show()
plt.imshow(other_mask);plt.show()
masked_both = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, other_mask)
plt.imshow(masked_both);plt.show()
```

[image: output]

What's the right way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: `masked_both = mask & other_mask` ?

Comment: It still gives me the same output like the last image here

Comment: Could you please provide minimal reproducible example? maybe a small image and masks? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is most likely that `other_mask` contains only positive values, but `imshow` scales the values. For example, min value of `other_mask` can be 100 and displayed as purple, and max value can be 200 and displayed as yellow. In that case masked_both will be the same as mask. You can check this by inspecting min and max values of your masks.

If this is the case, you can fix it by normalizing value ranges of both masks:

```
min_value = mask.min()
max_value = mask.max()
masked_normalized = (mask - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
```